# Using :after without content and width limitation

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

The menu is vertical and `ul` has a specific width.

What I want to do is the next thing:

```
------ ul width 300px ------
[link][image repeat........]
[link 2][image repeat .....]
```

[image]

- image `repeat-x` by `ul` width and `repeat-y` by text height

I tried using `a:after` but you cannot use it without a text / image content which gives you specific width. my image is only 3px width so it displays it one time and that it. what can I do to display the image until the end of the `ul` width (using `a:after` of course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usability-wise, a fixed-width list of links (with repeated pattern filling in the right side) should be clickable for the entire width of that line item, including the pattern fill.  However, since you seem very headstrong on using `:after`, how about this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/UVMBh/)?

You have to add in a character into the `content` attribute so that there is something there to have a background.  Unfortunately, for some reason I was not able to make `content: '\0020';` (encoded space) work, so I used something that was pretty benign and then set the color to transparent with `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.  Not all browsers support rgba, but there are resources that will fix that.  If you don't use that route, you could probably just set the pipe (|) character (since is aligns with the left edge of the patterned image) to the predominant color of the pattern.  In my case, I could've set it to a dark gray found in the image.

In any case, this should suffice to solve your problem.  Let me know if not.

Answer (score 1):

`content: "\00a0";` forces the appearance of your css styling in `:after` :-)